# How to send a parameter when switch from UITableController to another UITableController?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I use the code:

```
var newsListView: UIViewController!
    newsListView = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NewsList")
    sideMenuController()?.setContentViewController(newsListView)
```

to switch to another UITableController with indentifier is "NewsList" (etc).

And I want send attach a parameter (String) to ViewController NewsList can get it. So How I can do that! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just set data on the newsListView instance obtained from the storyboard.

`var newsListView = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier ("NewsList") as! YourClassName
newListView.property = some value
sideMenuController()?.setContentViewController(newsListView)`